# Error with bmp file-Exception thrown at 0x0FDD053F (ucrtbased.dll) in project 2017.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c, rgb, bmp

In this code I tried to get the first byte in each pixel, from a bmp file where the RGB values for each pixel are the same (like ff ff ff), and put these values into a matrix for further manipulations. The debugging process was terminated when the debugger reached "getting the first byte from each pixel"
and "Exception thrown at 0x0FDD053F (ucrtbased.dll) in project 2017.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD" appeared. What is the problem?(this is the first time I am working with bmp)  Thanks for helping!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    int width, height, w_count, h_count, padding;
    int **pix_mat;
    int a;
    FILE * dust_pic;
    fopen_s(&dust_pic, "d2.bmp", "rb");
    if (!dust_pic)
        printf_s("not found");
    fseek(dust_pic, 18, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&width, sizeof(int), 1, dust_pic);// getting width
    fread(&height, sizeof(int), 1, dust_pic);// getting height
    // FIND PADDING
    a = width;
    if (a % 4 != 0)
        padding = 4 - (a % 4);
    else
    padding = 0;

    //making matrix for pixels
    pix_mat = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*height);
    for (h_count = 0; h_count < height; h_count++)
        pix_mat[h_count] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*width);

    fseek(dust_pic, 54, SEEK_SET);
    // getting the first byte from each pixel
    for (h_count = 0; h_count < height; h_count++)
    {
        for (w_count = 0; w_count < width; w_count++)
        {
            fread(pix_mat[w_count][h_count], sizeof(char), 1, dust_pic);
            fseek(dust_pic, 2, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        fseek(dust_pic, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    fclose(dust_pic);
    // print the matrix.
    for (h_count = 0; h_count < height; h_count++)
    {
        for (w_count = 0; w_count < width; w_count++)
            printf_s("[%d],[%d]=%d  ", w_count, h_count, pix_mat[w_count][h_count]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    // free array
    for (h_count = 0; h_count < height; h_count++)
        free(pix_mat[h_count]);
    free(pix_mat);
}
```

Comment: CDCDCDCD is a magic number, it is the content of the memory allocated by malloc() in the debug build.  So you know that you are reading pix_mat content that was not initialized.  You are, you reversed the indices.  Other than reasoning it out, you debug code like this by *first* making it work on a tiny bitmap.  Start with 1x1, then 2x1, then 1x2 and by then you'll have found 98% of the problems.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more why there is a problem, I honestly don't understand

Comment: It should be pix_mat[h_count][w_count].  You reversed that.

Comment: @HansPassant : and it also needs an ampersand.

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function, regardless of what Visual Studio will allow.  1) `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )` and 2) `int main( void )`.   Notice that both signatures have a return type of `int`.

Comment: when the call to `fopen_s()` fails to open the file, then the code must not use that file pointer. AND error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  so these lines: `fopen_s(&dust_pic, "d2.bmp", "rb");
    if (!dust_pic)
        printf_s("not found");`  should be: `fopen_s(&dust_pic, "d2.bmp", "rb");
    if (!dust_pic)
    {    perror("fopen_s failed");  exit( EXIT_FAILURE); }`  The `perror()` function will also output the reason the system things the call failed.

Comment: when calling `fread()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in C, when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) do not cast the returned value.  It has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening (including optional) brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: note:  it is typical when writing/filling a matrix to place the 'row' index first, followed by the 'column' index.  Which is how the posted code is defining the matrix, but NOT how the matrix is being filled.

Comment: this is NOT how to access a non continguous matirx: `fread(pix_mat[w_count][h_count]`  rather use something similar to: `fread( &((*pix_mat[h_count)][w_count])`

Comment: when calling `fseek()`, always check the returned code to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 2, 4, 18, 54.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using an '`enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those magic numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the code is making several assumptions about the data in the image file.  A .bmp file can have pixels of 1,2 3, or 4 bytes each.  A .bmp file can have a variable number of 'prefered' pixel values.  A .bmp file can have a number of different internal formats, (which is indicated by the first two bytes in the file.  So the posted code may be usable (after corrections) for some .bmp files, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly checks for errors
3. properly cleans up, before exiting after any error events
4. properly reads the right size of data  from the file and saves that data into a properly declared array
5. properly references the rows and columns of the pixel matrix in memory
6. does not correct the assumptions about pixel width, offset to the pixels in the file, etc.

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fopen(), fclose(), perror(), fseek(), SEEK_SET
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), calloc(), free()

// prototypes
void cleanup( FILE *dust_pic, size_t height, char **pix_mat );


int main( void )
{
    size_t width, height, w_count, h_count;
    long padding;
    char **pix_mat;

    FILE * dust_pic;
    dust_pic = fopen("d2.bmp", "rb");
    if (!dust_pic)
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen_s successful

    fseek(dust_pic, 18, SEEK_SET);
    // check for error

    if( 1 != fread(&width, sizeof(int), 1, dust_pic) )// getting width
    {
        perror( "fread for width of image, in pixels, failed" );
        fclose( dust_pic );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fread successful

    if( 1 != fread(&height, sizeof(int), 1, dust_pic) )// getting height
    {
        perror( "fread for height of image, in pixels, failed" );
        fclose( dust_pic );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fread successful

    // calculate PADDING
    if ( width % 4 != 0)
        padding = (long)(4 - (width % 4));
    else
        padding = 0;

    //making matrix for pixels
    pix_mat = calloc(height, sizeof(char*));
    // check for malloc status
    if( !pix_mat )
    {
        perror( "calloc for array of pointers to char failed" );
        fclose( dust_pic );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, calloc successful

    for (h_count = 0; h_count < height; h_count++)
    {
        pix_mat[h_count] = malloc(sizeof(char)*width);
        // check for malloc status
        if( !pix_mat[h_count] )
        {
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            fclose( dust_pic );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful
    }

    // jump to beginning of pixel data in file
    if( -1 == fseek(dust_pic, 54, SEEK_SET) )
    {
        perror( "fseek to start of pixel data failed" );
        cleanup( dust_pic, height, pix_mat );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fseek successful

    // get the first byte (red) from each pixel
    for (h_count = 0; h_count < height; h_count++)
    {
        for (w_count = 0; w_count < width; w_count++)
        {
            if( 1 != fread( &((pix_mat[h_count])[w_count]), sizeof(char), 1, dust_pic) )
            {
                perror( "fread of 'red' pixel value failed" );
                cleanup( dust_pic, height, pix_mat );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, fread successful

            if( -1 == fseek(dust_pic, 2, SEEK_CUR) )
            {
                perror( "fseek to skip green/blue pixels failed" );
                cleanup( dust_pic, height, pix_mat );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, fseek successful
        }

        if( -1 == fseek(dust_pic, padding, SEEK_CUR) )
        {
            perror( "fseek to skip padding failed" );
            cleanup( dust_pic, height, pix_mat );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fseek successful
    }


    // print the matrix.
    for (h_count = 0; h_count < height; h_count++)
    {
        for (w_count = 0; w_count < width; w_count++)
            printf("[%lu],[%lu]=%3.3d  ", h_count, w_count, (pix_mat[h_count])[w_count]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    cleanup( dust_pic, height, pix_mat );
} // end function: main


void cleanup( FILE *dust_pic, size_t height, char **pix_mat )
{
    // free array
    for (size_t h_count = 0; h_count < height; h_count++)
        free(pix_mat[h_count]);
    free(pix_mat);

    fclose( dust_pic );
} // end function: cleanup
```